# Read Binary from a .z file with no header in python

Tags: python, file, binary, compression

Im trying to read the binary packed in to a .z file in python, the file has no magic number or header so standard unzip tools can't be used.

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: `.Z` ? the format created by unix `compress` ?

Comment: Yes it has been compressed and I want to decompress it myself in python. But need to access compressed data first.

Comment: It might be from the prehistoric "pack" command, which used the .z suffix. Can you provide the first several bytes of the file in hex?